# snmp linux timezone

Tags: linux, snmp

I have the oid to get system time from linux, but is it possible to determine the system timezone via snmp on a redhat/centos box?

Comment: What format is the raw time data coming in? Sometimes the time zone is embedded (e.g. `date` command).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The hrSystemDate.0 object returns the local timezone:

```
HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrSystemDate.0 = STRING: 2011-3-24,6:20:24.0,-6:0
                                                                 ^^^^
```

The suffix shows the time offset from GMT.

Comment: That looks good, is that setting it though? Or retrieving the value? I need to retrieve the value from the host.

Comment: That was done with snmpget (retrieving it).

Comment: thanks, looks like the oid for hrSystemDate is 1.3.6.1.2.1.25.6.3.1.5.1? That returns a hex string. When I use snmpwalk with the above text query it doesn't recognize HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrSystemDate.0 ...

Comment: Then you need to set the MIBS to load properly if that's the case.  Try snmpwalk HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrSystemDate and it should format it properly.  The contents of the string is a series of numbers that represents the above text.  See the DateAndTime textual convention in the SNMPv2-TC.txt MIB file that should be on your system.

Comment: Thanks! I got it working, in my case, had to download correct mibs on the polling host, and that fixed it.

Comment: For those on ubuntu 10.10 x86_64, default install, where ubuntu is the polling host (where you're querying FROM), need the following mibs in /usr/share/mibs/netsnmp/ - IANAifType-MIB, SNMPv2-MIB, SNMPv2-SMI, SNMPv2-TC,HOST-RESOURCES-MIB.  These fixed this issue for me at least.